# c++ Recursively multiply 2 integers using addition

Tags: c++, recursion

I'm trying to write code for homework that uses recursion and addition to multiply two integers together. But, I'm currently getting a lot of error messages, and I'm not even sure if I'm on the right track. And, just to double-check, this is recursive, right? I wrote another program for this problem which worked great until I realized it wasn't actually recursive. Here's the full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int result;
int m;
int n;

int rmultiply(int m, int n)
{
    if(n > 1)
        return(m + (rmultiply(n - 1)));

    else if ((m == 0) || (n == 0))
        return 0;
    else if (n == 1)
        return m;
}

int main(m, n)
    {
    cout << "Enter two integers to multiply" << endl; //prompt user to input 2 integers
    cin >> m >> n; //store them in variable m and n

    result = rmultiply(m,n);
    cout << result;
    }
```

Error 1: Too few arguments to function 'int rmultiply(int, int)'

```
return(m + (rmultiply(n - 1)));
```

Warning: control reaches end of non-void function

Error 2(for code lines below): Expression list treated as compound expression in initializer

Error 3: Expected ',' or ';' before'{' token

Warning: left operand of comma operator has no effect

```
int main(m, n)
{
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This is just stupid. Nobody should ever define multiplication this way, not even as an exercise.

Comment: The prof wants us to learn how to use recursion properly. His decision as to assignments, not mine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are calling the function again in this line,

```
return(m + (rmultiply(n - 1)));
```

You have to pass another variable.

Also, it will be a good idea to name the global variables m and n something different. It wont affect the programming, but just for better understanding. Because the m and n variable inside function `rmultiply` will always be different than the global m and n (unless passed by reference).

For the other errors, define a type of variable in line,

```
main(m, n)
```

As an integer perhaps.

And, in the `main` make sure that an integer is returned. Because in the function definition you have `int main`

Comment: Um...forgive my ignorance, but what do you mean by passing another variable to that line? Do I need to create another variable for it?

Comment: And, thanks, adding int did fix most of the other problems. Not sure how I missed that.

Comment: You can pass the same `m` variable. `rmultiply(m,n-1)`

Answer (score 1):

Logic for this should be "add a to itself as many as b times". Let's take an example of 2*3. This can be reduced to (3 times 2) that is: 2 + 2 + 2. Following should be the code implementation for this.

```
int product(int a, int b)
{
    if( a ==0 || b == 0)
    {
       return 0;
    }
    if (b==1)
    {
        return a;
    }
    else
    {
        return a + product(a, b - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please put some more effort in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
   int f(int x,int y)
  {
        if (y==0)
           return 0;
       int z=f(x,y/2);
         if (y % 2==0)
           return 2*z;
        else
           return x+2*z;
 }
```

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to explain how does this code work.

Comment: I think this violates the spirit of the question because you're using `/`, `*`, and `%`, which are all in the multiplicative family of operations.  You can get rid of the `2*z` using `z+z`, and use bitwise operations `&1` and `>>1` for the even/odd check and division by 2, respectively, but the prof might still object that they're not in the addition family.