# How to perform a multiplication using only additions and assignments?

Tags: c++, math

How do I change the following program, so that it performs the same Task, but using only additions and assignments?

I can only do max 27 additions, and the Output has to be generated in a single Input.
Loops and other control flow operations are **not** allowed

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int a;
    std::cout << "Enter number: ";
    std::cin >> a;

    std::cout << a*29 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is not a c++ question . It's a math question

Comment: Please, give all restrictions right away. The last edit you did just invalidated a few answers people spent time on! I'd right an answer but I fear you change the rules once again. I'm voting to close the question.

Comment: Use recursion. See e.g. [this duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19897824/c-recursively-multiply-2-integers-using-addition) and [this one too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20289063/how-to-multiply-using-addition).

Comment: @YSC Nope, that's it

Comment: Either that, or use temporaries  for a binary or tertiary multiplication, i.e. `b = a + a;  c = b + b;` etc. Return `e+d+c+a`.

Answer (score 7):

Another approach that requires 7 `+`:

```
int M1  = a;        // 1a
int M2  = M1 + M1;  // 2a
int M4  = M2 + M2;  // 4a
int M8  = M4 + M4;  // 8a
int M16 = M8 + M8;  // 16a
int res = M16 + M8 + M4 + M1; // 29a
```

The result is constructed from the binary pattern of the multiplier, i.e. 29 decimal is 0001.1101 binary. So we need to add M16, M8, M4 and M1 (and exclude M2).

Comment: Yes, this could well be what the teacher wants. A way of teaching binary?

Comment: I think it's a way to introduce recursion and trees.  "No loops" is the giveaway.

Answer (score 6):

This is not general, and it cannot be, but to multiply just by 29 you can do this:

```
// x is input
int t = x;  // x*1
x = x + x;
x = x + x;
t = t + x;  // x*5
x = x + x;
t = t + x;  // x*13
x = x + x;
t = t + x;  // x*29
```

This is just unrolled binary multiplication, like the similar answers, but without naming the temporary results. The additions to `t` correspond to the set bits in 29.

Answer (score 2):

This way you can do it with 21 additions.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int a;
    std::cout << "Enter number: ";
    std::cin >> a;
    int b = (a+a+...+a) // 10 times
    b = b + b;
    b = b + (a + a + a ... + a ); // 9 times
    std::cout << b << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you use an additional var?

```
b = a + a + a//3 times a 
b = b + b + b//9 times a
b = b + b + b//27 times a
b = b + a + a//29 times a
```

Answer (score 1):

Multiplication is just a repeated addition. Use a loop for this. Do you know how many times your loop should execute? Yes! So use a for loop.

So here is the plan:

1. Get input
2. Use a for loop to perform the addition
3. Output `sum`

Example:

```
// get input
int input;
std::cout << "Enter number: ";
std::cin >> input;

// use a for loop to perform the addition
int sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i< 29; ++i)
    sum += a;

// output result
std::cout << sum << std::endl;
```

Comment: Read it through more closely. Loops and control flow operations are not allowed

Answer (score 0):

,resRepetitive addition is multiplication -- mathematically

So repeat addition of `a` for `n` number of times. A simple `for/while`  loop can do this

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int a,i,temp=0;
    std::cout << "Enter number: ";
    std::cin >> a;
    for(i=1;i<=29;i++)
        temp+=a;//add a repeatedly for 'n' number of times. Here 29 as per your requirement. a*n  
    std::cout << temp <<std::endl; 
    return 0;
}
```

**Without loop**

```
int b=0,result=0;
b=a+a+a+a+a+a+a;\\adding for 7 times
result=b+b+b+b+a;\\4 times 7 (of a)= 28+a= 29 times (of a).
```

This involves 10 addition.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only allowed to use `+` and `=`, and are not allowed to cheat by introducing other variables, there is no way of doing this unless you indulge in a bit of *undefined behaviour* and allow yourself something of the form

```
... + (a += ...) + ...
```

where `...` is any number of `a +`. The trick here is that `(a += ...)` changes the value of `a` part way through evaluation of the expression.

Tempting as it may be, alas this is **not** portable C++ since `+=` and `+` are not sequencing points. On your classroom compiler, you might be able to get this to work.

See https://ideone.com/fC3fai, you can see that

```
(a + a + a + a + a + (a += a + a + a) + a + a + a + a + a)
```

does the job on that *particular* compiler (at the time of writing). (For what it's worth, it also does the correct thing in Java where the expression is well-defined).

Comment: you could multiply by 32 (`<<5`) then subtract three times ;)

Comment: @YSC: Indeed, I took this literally to mean just `+` and `=`, squeezing in `+=`.

Comment: you could also use recursion

Comment: @YSC to my mind, recursion is a control flow operation, so is banned too. I was thinking about expression statements, but they aren't portable either.

Comment: It makes sense.

Comment: @YSC: I'm being a bit naughty but my hypothesis is that the teacher is not aware that such a solution as I give is not portable.

Comment: This is evil but unfortunately probably true.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this -

```
b = a + a + a + a + a + a + a + a + a + a + a + a + a + a + a; // equivalent to a*15

b += b -a;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add value multiple times:

```
int sum=0;
for(int i=0; i<multipler; i++){
    sum+=a; //adds value of a to itself
}
return sum;
```

If you want to multiple only by 2 you can just shift left:

```
a = a << 1;
```

Comment: "Loops and other control flow operations are not allowed"

Comment: If multipler is known, you can do something like this (for 29):
`output=a<<4; //*16
output+=a<<3; //*8
output+=a<<2; //*4
output+=a; //*1`